# Rails 5 nested form won't create child records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms, nested-attributes, has-many-through

I've been stuck on this for hours. I don't understand how nested forms and using 'accepts_nested_attributes_for' is supposed to work.

I have a 'form_for' my new List, and a 'fields_for' it's list_items. Here is the fields_for the list_items.

**fields_for :list_items**

https://pastebin.com/NxZWGeYj

Now, 'list_item' is *:through* part of List's has_many_through associations with a User's 'user_items'. This nested form supposed to submit the information from the 'user_item' needed to build a 'list_item' that will belong to the new list. It seems like somewhere along the way the parameters for my child items are not being delivered...

```
Started POST "/list" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-08-17 18:18:04 -0400
Processing by ListsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"203D1bpQZzKU9J0gyUPOvQNFbkxmREyDLmb4IdARaDNjVX5fqCydg5dUe/d2NgWocU6AFkC+hWl5QCpfu9GLqw==", "list"=>{"name"=>"", "list_items_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"user_item_id"=>"1", "quantity"=>"1"}, "1"=>{"user_item_id"=>"2", "quantity"=>"1"}, "2"=>{"quantity"=>"1"}, "3"=>{"quantity"=>"1"}, "4"=>{"quantity"=>"1"}, "5"=>{"quantity"=>"1"}, "6"=>{"quantity"=>"1"}, "7"=>{"quantity"=>"1"}, "8"=>{"quantity"=>"1"}}}, "commit"=>"Submit"}
```

And instead the @list fails to save and two flash error messages pop up:

```
["List items list must exist", "List items user item must exist"]
```

This tells me that somehow my list_items aren't being build correctly, or that my fields for isn't right...or something. I honestly am stuck. Anyway, here's my Lists Controller:

https://pastebin.com/kDZHQ6vB

and my List model:

https://pastebin.com/MTH8Yf2S

and again the fields_for :list_items

https://pastebin.com/NxZWGeYj

I really hope this makes sense. Thanks

**UPDATE**

Something I noticed in the parameters being sent by this form is that my nested params hash appears to be part array...?

```
"list_items_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"user_item_id"=>"1", "quantity"=>"1"}, "1"=>{"user_item_id"=>"2", "quantity"=>"1"}
```

This is not reflected in my list_params and may be the issue...still not sure what the fix is though:

```
def list_params
  params.require(:list).permit(:name, list_items_attributes: {:user_item_id, :quantity})
end
```

Comment: you see the gem cocoon? https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon

Comment: Can you post action `new` of your Lists Controller

Comment: I build each item in the view itself